# Python encoding errors

Tags: python

I try to scrape website and print meta fields. I got an `UnicodeEncodeError` but I resolved it by using chcp 65001 in my terminal (I am using Windows). Now it works fine but some sites gives me strange results. I get "Ä‡wiczenia" instead of "Ćwiczenia". Other sites gives proper values ("Ćwiczenia" for example).

Why one time it is ok and another time it is not?

This is my method:

```
def description(self):
    description = self.soup.find_all(attrs={'name':
                                            ['description', 'Description']})
    if description:
        return(description[0]['content'])
```

It gives me good result on one page. On another

```
if description:
        return(description[0]['content'].encode("windows-1252").decode("utf-8"))
```

fix it (I get proper encoding) but when I open previous site with this method I get an error:

> "'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u015b' in position 69"

How can I solve this?

Comment: If you know how the site is encoded, then you'd know how to decode it. Perhaps https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35836/how-to-tell-the-browser-the-character-encoding-of-a-html-website-regardless-of-s ?

Comment: This problematic site is in utf-8. It should look fine.